# MySQL grouping multiple columns issue

Tags: mysql

i have a database table containing events:

```
INSERT INTO events(device, link, down_time, up_time) VALUES('d1', 'l1', '2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:05:00');
INSERT INTO events(device, link, down_time, up_time) VALUES('d2', 'l2', '2015-01-01 00:00:01', '2015-01-01 00:00:2');
INSERT INTO events(device, link, down_time, up_time) VALUES('d2', 'l2', '2015-01-01 00:00:03', '2015-01-01 00:00:05');
INSERT INTO events(device, link, down_time, up_time) VALUES('d3', 'l3', '2015-01-01 00:00:06', '2015-01-01 00:00:09');

| device | link | down_time           | up_time             | id |
| d1     | l1   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-01 00:05:00 |  1 |
| d2     | l2   | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 |  2 |
| d2     | l2   | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 |  3 |
| d3     | l3   | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 |  4 |
```

i want to find events, overlapping in time and am using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM events a
JOIN events b
ON a.down_time <= b.up_time AND a.up_time >= b.down_time
WHERE a.link regexp 'l[12]' AND b.link regexp 'l[12]' and a.id != b.id;
```

This displays 4 rows showing overlaps, however rows 1 and 2 show the same overlap events as rows 3 and 4. I want add a group clause to query so that i only display rows 1 and 2 but cannot get it worked out.

```
| device | link | down_time           | up_time             | id | device | link | down_time           | up_time             | id |
| d2     | l2   | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 |  2 | d1     | l1   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-01 00:05:00 |  1 |
| d2     | l2   | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 |  3 | d1     | l1   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-01 00:05:00 |  1 |
| d1     | l1   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-01 00:05:00 |  1 | d2     | l2   | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 |  2 |
| d1     | l1   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-01 00:05:00 |  1 | d2     | l2   | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 |  3 |
```

many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting duplicates because your `a.id != b.id` allows comparing the rows in both "orders", by changing it to `a.id < b.id` you can allow only "earlier" records to be compared with later ones.

Edit: removed "side note", I misread the overlap condition.

Comment: I thought it was fairly straight forward, but I'll add a bit of elaboration in an edit.

Comment: yes i see what you mean re duplicates. re side note not sure what you mean? The first row in query results shows that events.id 2 range overlaps events.id 1 range. The second row in results shows  that events.id 3 range also overlaps events.id 1 range. This is what i need. Many thanks for your help this looks to be  potential solution !

Comment: Did some further tests on a larger dataset and thie query does not show what i expect ..willdo further tests and update ..thanks again !

Comment: I double checked the overlap condition, and found I must have misread it; so ignore the side note (I've removed it). How are the results differing from what you expect?

Comment: i repeated and discovered a silly mistake so false alarm. i have however an additional requirement. i want to show the overlap duration and am using the following test in php:

Comment: i will create a new question for this as its related but different

Answer (score 1):

Change the ID comparison in the  `ON` clause so it only selects one of the two orderings:

```
ON a.id < b.id AND a.down_time <= b.up_time AND a.up_time >= b.down_time
```

Comment: ok Barmer this looks to be a potential solution many thanks !

Comment: I just noticed that you already have an `id` column in the query, you just didn't show it in the table data. So I simplified the answer.